# __coerce__ vs. __ihook__ difference?

Tags: python

in python, you have `__coerce__` and `__ihook__`. According to [PEP 203](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/) (Augmented Assigments) they are both invoked, in this order to perform in place operations on objects, with `__coerce__` called first, and `__ihook__` next. I don't know if these methods have been made specifically for augmented assignment, but I would like to know the practical difference between the two.

Comment: As a side note, `__coerce__()` is gone in Python 3.

Comment: @Sven : interesting. What is the new approach ?

Comment: Basically, the operators do the type conversions themselves.  This is more reasonable, since the type of the result depends on both, the type of the operands and the operator.  For example the sum of `2` and `-1` is an integer, while `2**-1` is a floating point number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `__ihook__` in that PEP stands for one of the following methods:

```
    __iadd__
    __isub__
    __imul__
    __idiv__
    __imod__
    __ipow__
    __ilshift__
    __irshift__
    __iand__
    __ixor__
    __ior__
```

They are *in place* operations of their respective `__hook__`s. For example, `a+=b` does something like `a.__iadd__(b)`.

`__coerce__` on the other hand exists to coerce arguments to a common type. What this means is that `coerce(1, 2.0)` returns `(1.0, 2.0)`.

So the difference is that they do completely different things. Sometimes they have to work together, for example when you do `a=1; a+= 2.0` - first Python coerces the type, then it calls `a.__iadd__(2.0)`.